# Typescript thinks indexed access type T[EventKeys<T>] isn't a MyEvent

Tags: typescript

I have an interface for custom event listeners, so that classes can provide events which others can listen to:

```
interface MyEvent<F extends (...args: any[]) => void> {
    listen(callback: F): void;
}

class Foo {
    declare numberEvent: MyEvent<(x: number) => void>;
    declare stringEvent: MyEvent<(x: string) => void>;
    declare somethingElse: number;
}
```

I am writing a function which listens to multiple events belonging to the same object, which should be called like this:

```
listenAll(foo, {
    numberEvent: x => console.log(x + 1),
    stringEvent: x => console.log(x.charAt(0)),
});
```

To make this work, I have the following two utility types: `EventKeys` gets the keys corresponding to events declared in a class, and `CallbacksFor` defines an object containing the appropriate callbacks for each event in a class.

```
type EventKeys<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends MyEvent<any> ? K : never}[keyof T]
type CallbacksFor<T> = {[K in EventKeys<T>]: T[K] extends MyEvent<infer F> ? F : never}
```

The problem is writing the `listenAll` function:

```
function listenAll<T>(obj: T, callbacks: CallbacksFor<T>): void {
    const keys = Object.keys(callbacks) as (EventKeys<T>)[];

    for(const key of keys) {
        const e = obj[key];
        const f = callbacks[key];
        // error: Property 'listen' does not exist on type 'T[EventKeys<T>]'.
        e.listen(f);
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CiA3C4A8AYshAB6QgAmAzsgBQB0TcUA5tQFzJwjoDaAXQCUyALwA+ZNgD2wSpIDeAWABQydcgA2wahToI4mzQCNEAay6EhXGXIDcqgL6rVYdAAcUOPGADSEdGp8ABVJUWQFPl9kUGQzAOkYZGCBLmCogRJyPBo0LFwCHnRJAH5kaK4QCFwoRz549ETkgVcPFABhQxNzakJpKBCwiKiYkGRvcH9AwdTkjKyKXIwJsHxQGGhkQlKt5Erq6GcVVRgAVxAEMGBpMe1dPABBI0G6aWMAKzSAGmQDI1MEGZOMhOv8en0BqFrFJZJQIqoNL8bro4gFaOEAPIfCCXBgNaj6LoAoEiOC0OgrKZBKGCBzHNQaGD9fTIsCo9DIJr4kTKBmI9QIVkkMScj71AICOn8jSCkAopLhP7dQHUcXoSUI6XIAD02pIUCg-S4AAVDZ4oG5kAByO4UK3ISjSCC0EDSNlkHRsm7INyea3pSlomZWhia6UQBi2vB0GBCKUaI5HVQITRk2h9aTwvkOnGpqAoECnAC2xmgKy4ywKqzopEqxdLUBEEhhcnE8fUlFzLBQuigoFY5byK3wNa4vf7Tcktnk7ZzKe7yGo0iLEDAAAt+5hNNQIHWS9A6UmVLL5dJM+EqgB3LZnuhx1RRkBPTQxs8-XmIwv7qCD0hiSQntImgRpo0isDWyAANTIAAjEIXxhouYB9iAA5Vlwf7NoBwGRmBNYMAga4sA8YB0AADEI8FOPeKhAA)

The problem is, Typescript doesn't realise that the indexed access type `T[EventKeys<T>]` must be a `MyEvent`. Even using a type assertion `const e = obj[key] as MyEvent<any>;` gives a compilation error, because Typescript thinks these types are completely unrelated. But `EventKeys<T>` is defined as the subset of keys of `T` whose values are assignable to `MyEvent<any>`, so logically `obj[key]` must be a `MyEvent`.

I don't mind the type assertion when using `Object.keys`, but I'd like to know if this function can be written without something like `e = obj[key] as unknown as MyEvent<any>;`, which uses another two type assertions.

---

I did find a way to make the `listenAll` function type-check, by changing its generic type parameters like below, but unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem because `K` can't be inferred from context at the call-site.

```
function listenAll<K extends PropertyKey, T extends Record<K, MyEvent<any>>>(/* ... */): void {
    // ...
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-QB3d2WiAMO56GBCC0aI5HVQITSi2h9f3a+mUSFZqAR04AW2M0BWXHhPnwdFIlXLlagIgkVLk4hT6kLmZYKF0UFArGreRW9cbyEHw7bkls8m7yF7xYH0jLEDAIeHmE01AgTYr0Fl6ZU1tt0n94Sqka2F7oydU3uQxlONqjyE34ZitB4AaDofDDhHx9B42HLHx1SSNxPGQAByXNYO-X1pBtbNgFYEA4GMTQUDAf13BYOB10gYMmmglBYIhKEoBhL4fmgf4AjhfI6yRcRYIYZBVATR4jDoRVpCBfMNBAZsqwRLhSDESR9WkHD42kVgG2QABqZAAEYhABGMpzAIcQBHCTkCk9tZPkzRFIbBgEBDFgHjAOgAAYhC0pwHxUIA)

Comment: Are you trying to implement the observer pattern?

Comment: @Jason Something like that, except the events are not necessarily triggered on state changes (and some of the classes which expose events are otherwise immutable).

Comment: It's sort of hard to have a back and forth here, but does something like this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCiA3CA7YUC8UDeBYAUFEVKJAFxQDkKArgLYBGEATpVAD5UDOwzAligDmlAgF8CBAIYMezSQGN08gDaSuXKAHkZLZMwA8SVMAB8OAsShhmAe2ARFEACZRlfHqhZcKAQWZyQfQAKCGQ0CiM0AEpMMxoUAGsUGwB3FDMsAG0AXQBuC2ICojAaBjd5KGTgPgAzEBCw4AjGmLxCS2JgAAt3ADo3DxQvXpqbZngFLqCggfsh5hiMM1nPZgbjKKj89qJxfD2CFTUNADEbGygIAA85pw1tLl0WfThI03N2sSA) help?

The listeners would be responsible for their behavior based on the Event type.

Comment: @Jason That's (a simplified form of) the implementation of the `MyEvent` interface, which I omitted from my question because it's not necessary to reproduce the issue in the `listenAll` function.

Comment: I was thinking the simplification would avoid the issue by making all registered listeners "listenAll". They'd just need to check the `type` property to know what code to execute. Sorry if that doesn't help.

Comment: @Jason Oh, I see. That's an interesting idea which could work, but I don't think I would want to change the design that much just to avoid an `as unknown as ...` type assertion. For the purpose of this question, I'm interested in knowing if there is a way to make Typescript aware that `T[EventKeys<T>]` must be a `MyEvent` due to how `EventKeys` is defined. It might be achievable by giving `T` some upper bound, or changing the definition of `EventKeys`, or (less ideally) making a different type assertion in the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240272/discussion-between-jason-and-kaya3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to give `T` a self-referential upper bound `Record<EventKeys<T>, MyEvent<any>>`:

```
function listenAll<T extends Record<EventKeys<T>, MyEvent<any>>>(obj: T, callbacks: CallbacksFor<T>): void {
    // ...
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CiA3C4A8AYshAB6QgAmAzsgBQB0TcUA5tQFzJwjoDaAXQCUyALwA+ZNgD2wSpIDeAWABQydcgA2wahToI4mzQCNEAay6EhXGXIDcqgL6rVYdAAcUOPGADSEdGp8ABVJUWQFPl9kUGQzAOkYZGCBLmCogRJyPBo0LFwCHnRJAH5kaK4QCFwoRz549ETkgVcPFABhQxNzakJpKBCwiKiYkGRvcH9AwdTkjKyKXIwJsHxQGGhkQlKt5Erq6GcVVRgAVxAEMGBpMe1dPABBIxCFnNoAJQgEfsp8FamgqEADR5Fb4IriSF0aTGABWaRBBiMpgQZk4yE6yJ6fQGoWsUlklAiqg0yG+IF0cQCtHCAHk4V8wAwGtR9F0UWiRHBaHR-tTBkJBA5jmoNDB+vobpSGsgmiyRMpRaT1OTKShwjDYfUAgJhcqNKqwMgkuEkd1UdRtehdST9SQGHc9DAhHqNEcjqoEJpubQ+tJiUrkJQvt6oCgQKcALbGaArLjLAqrOikSpRmNQEQSAlycSu9TBr0sFC6KCgVhx0GJ-DJrglsuZyS2eR5oMhovIajSSMQMAACzLmE01Agqej0GFHpUhuN0n94SqAHctrO6C7VI7HkY6OLpCDFaSI2OoBXSGJJKrpJoIA7pKxk8gANTIACMQiBtvUdZA5cTXFPWYvK8bzvUgGAQXsWAeMA6AABiEN8nDXFQgA)

This upper bound *should* be a tautology, since `EventKeys<T>` is defined as precisely those keys whose values are of type `MyEvent<any>`. The problem was that Typescript couldn't figure that out for itself, but specifying it in the upper bound allows Typescript to infer that `obj[key]` has type `MyEvent<...>` when `key` has type `EventKeys<T>`, as required.

The upper bound will be checked at the call-site, where `T` is realised as a concrete type; although Typescript can't figure out that the constraint is satisfied for all types, Typescript can at least confirm that it is satisfied for whatever concrete type is provided, and so there is no type error at the call-site.