# Trying to limit Typescript function to string properties of a given type

Tags: typescript

Basically I am trying to write a function which returns a sorter function for a specified string property of a given type.

```
sortString<User>('name')
```

So far I have the following :

```
type KeysAssignableToType<O, T> = {
    [K in keyof O]-?: O[K] extends T ? K : never;
}[keyof O];

export const sortString = <T>(field: KeysAssignableToType<T, string | undefined>) => (a: T, b: T): number => {
    if (a[field]) {
        return b[field] ? a[field].localeCompare(b[field]) : 1
    }
    return b[field] ? -1 : 0
}
```

But there is the following problem. TS gives me a `TS2339: Property 'localeCompare' does not exist on type 'T[KeysAssignableToType ]'`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `KeysAssignableToType<T, string>` works only for outter scope, not for inner. Current version of TS is unable to figure out that `a[field]` is a string type if condition evaluates to `true`. Consider this [workaround](https://tsplay.dev/m3y7Lw)

Comment: Your two problems are two different things; could you please pick one of them to be the focus of your question?  The optional property thing seems like you should just be writing `KeysAssignableToType<T, string | undefined>`, whereas the other one has to do with type inference and can be addressed by adding a constraint the compiler understand like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXKD8W).  Which one is the real question here?

Comment: @jcalz the first (a) problem, I figured out the solution to the optional property issue shortly after posting. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: So could you [edit] the question to remove references to the second problem?  And then someone can post answers to the main question

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70413082/12299000) which I had a while ago. A solution is to declare the type parameter as `<T extends Record<KeysAssignableToType<T, string | undefined>, string | undefined>>` instead of just `<T>`. Ugly, but it works. (Note that you'll still get problems because of the `undefined`, which you can solve by declaring `const aField = a[field], bField = b[field];` and using those variables instead of repeated indexed accesses.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a limitation or missing feature of TypeScript.  There's no type operator that behaves like `KeysAssignableToType<O, T>` where the compiler can understand that `O[KeysAssignableToType<O, T>]` is assignable to `T` when `O` or `T` are [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  The sort of higher-order logic encoded there just isn't available to the compiler.  There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992) to support such a type operator.  Until and unless this is implemented, all we have are workarounds.

One workaround is to move (or add) the constraint so that instead of (or in addition to) saying that a key type `K` is constrained to `KeysAssignableToType<O, T>`, we say that the *object* type `O` is constrained to something like `Record<K, T>`.  The compiler will let you index into a `Record<K, T>` with a key `K`, even if `K` and `T` are generic.  For example:

```
type ObjWithKeys<O, T> =
    { [P in KeysAssignableToType<O, T>]?: T };

export const sortString = <T extends ObjWithKeys<T, string | undefined>>(
    field: KeysAssignableToType<T, string | undefined>) => (a: T, b: T): number => {
        const aField = a[field];
        const bField = b[field];
        if (aField) {
            return bField ? aField.localeCompare(bField) : 1
        }
        return bField ? -1 : 0
    }
```

This works because we've constrained `T` to the equivalent to `Record<KeysAssignableToType<O, T>, T>` (although I added the [optional modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) so that it doesn't have a problem with optional properties).  So when we index into `a` or `b` with `field`, the compiler knows that the result will be assignable to `string | undefined`.

Please note that I copied `a[field]` and `b[field]` into their own variables `aField` and `bField` before [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) them with truthiness checks (side note: you really want `undefined` and `""` to be equivalent in sort order? okay I guess).  That's due to a bug/limitation mentioned at [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530); the compiler isn't able to narrow properties if the property index isn't a simple [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), and `field` is certainly not of a simple type.  By using a separate variable, we can forget about property indices completely and focus on a single value.

Anyway, now it all works as desired:

```
interface User {
    name: string,
    optionalProp?: string,
    age: number
}

sortString<User>('name') // ok
sortString<User>('optionalProp') // ok
sortString<User>('age') // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=33#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)